# Android: Do I need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in order com.squareup.picasso to use disk cache?

Tags: android, picasso

Do I need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in order Picasso to use disk cache ?

I am using com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2

I guess YES but I couldn't find anything about it in the webpage

Comment: yes..for caching you need permission..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need that permission.  There is definitely no reason to write a cache to the external storage.
By default (if you don't supply your own OkHttpDownloader or configure it yourself), Picasso will `OkHttpClient.setCache(Cache)` using the following File:
`File cache = new File(context.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "picasso-cache");`
[See Picasso's Utils class.](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Utils.java)

Note that Picasso itself does no disk caching; disk caching is the HTTP client's job.